# SVN shared password db on Windows server

Tags: svn

I'd like to have a shared password-db file for several repositories on my home svn server (run under Windows).  I've figured out that I need to set all the repositories to have the same `realm`, but I can't figure out how to just put in an absolute path to the shared password-db. I.e. the full path is something like:

`c:\svn.users\passwrd`

What do I set the `password-db` setting to in svnserve.conf so it can find this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer using google.  The `password-db` setting is a relative path unless the first character is a `/`. This works great on *nix systems, but in windows, not so good.  The solution is that it supports UNC paths and `//./` represents the current machine. So, if you use:

`//./c:/svn.users/passwrd`

it works!

Answer (score 1):

I really like using ViusalSVN server.  It takes some of the complexities out of managing an SVN repository and you can even use Windows authentication to manage what users have access to what.  Give it a try:

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/